# Сколько денег ему нужно(,) и кто может ему помочь

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

1. *Сколько денег ему нужно(,) и кто может ему помочь — тема разговора.*
2. *Сколько денег ему нужно(,) и кто может ему помочь*

Если делать разбор первого предложения по членам предложения, то можно сказать, что *Сколько денег ему нужно (,) и кто может ему помочь* - это подлежащее, а тема разговора - сказуемое?

Второе предложение - это заголовок (не вопросительное предложение).

По правилу запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой безличные или неопределенно-личные предложения с одинаковой формой сказуемого или если части сложносочиненного предложения побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения.

Сколько денег ему нужно - безличное, кто может ему помочь - личное.

*Сколько денег ему нужно и кто может ему помочь* не побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения.

Нужна ли перед *и* запятая?

Answer (score 2):

> По правилу, запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного
>   предложения представляют собой безличные или неопределенно-личные
>   предложения с одинаковой формой сказуемого или если части
>   сложносочиненного предложения побудительные, вопросительные или
>   восклицательные предложения.

doom, запятая в подобном *заголовке*, если он состоит из двух частей, вообще-то ставится по особым правилам, попросту говоря - всегда. К сожалению, я в явном виде эти правила видела прописанными только для союза "или", но, полагаю, можно обобщить.

Вот в отношении первого вашего предложения можно спорить. Я думаю, что да, ваш вариант грамматического разбора вполне уместен (хотя, возможно, и не единственен). И при таком разборе получается, что запятая не нужна. Но тут не буду настаивать, всегда испытывала нелюбовь к грамматике подобного стиля высказываний. Такими фразами только приказы солдатам отдавать да лозунги о светлом прошлом писать.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом пункте правила особо подчеркивается роль интонации. Даже если нет вопросительного знака, остается вопросительная интонация, хоть и не так ярко выраженная. Поэтому запятую в таких случаях не ставят.

Из-за обсуждения в комментариях добавляю к ответу еще несколько скриншотов. Первый — о местоимениях (из справочника по синтаксису Г. И. Кустовой), второй и третий — о критериях выделения вопросительных предложений ("Русская грамматика" — акад. изд. инст. В. Виноградова;  справочник  Н. С. Валгиной).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, что вопросительной интонации здесь всё-таки нет, как нет ее в предложении следующего вида: А теперь поговорим о том, сколько денег ему нужно и кто может ему помочь. В этом случае  в качестве союзных слов используются относительные, а не вопросительные местоимения. В то же время на интонации связь предложений отражается, так как они  читаются одной фразой.

Comment: На мой взгляд, здесь местоимения именно вопросительные. Между "темой разговора" и двумя другими частями связь бессоюзная. Эти части вовсе не являются придаточными. Что касается произношения без паузы, о котором Вы тоже пишете, то в правиле об этом факторе не упоминается.

Comment: Комментарий касался заголовка, где нет бессоюзной связи, только два предложения, связанных союзом И. Как Вы определяете вид синтаксической конструкции в этом случае ?  И по поводу местоимений для обоих вариантов: нет знака вопроса - значит, нет вопросительных местоимений и нет  вопросительной интонации. Мне кажется, что это так.

Comment: Придаточными Вы называли эти предложения не в комментариях, а в своем ответе (до его последнего изменения). В обоих примерах речь идет о вопросительных местоимениях. Соединительный союз "и" служит для сочинительной связи. Относительными такие местоимения могли бы быть только в сложноподчиненном предложении. Но думаю, что автору вопроса важнее то, что мы согласны в одном: запятая там не нужна :)

Comment: Исправлена ошибка/опечатка, но сейчас уже обсуждается не этот вопрос и не авторские интересы, а терминология, наличие вопросительной интонации и т.д. И пока я не вижу  ответа на следующие вопросы: как определить вид синтаксической конструкции   в заголовке, можно ли считать местоимения вопросительными при отсутствии знака вопроса и вопросительной интонации (называть предложение "немного вопросительным" как-то не хотелось бы).

Comment: Предложение( заголовок) я бы отнес к сложносочиненному и поставил бы запятую.

Comment: Sergey, так вопрос автора и не об этом был. А про вопросительные и относительные местоимения лучше поискать в каких-нибудь справочниках по грамматике, если эта тема интересует.

Comment: Первый источник – о местоимениях. Второй – о критериях выделения вопросительных предложений. О вопросительном знаке как обязательном элементе в грамматике не сказано. А в заголовках он часто опускается, чтобы подчеркнуть информативность статьи (если она отвечает на вопрос, поставленный в заголовке). Само же предложение остается вопросительным по своей сути.

Comment: Aurora, это все верно, но в вопросе действительно есть комментарий, что это заголовок. Я не знаю, как тут работает это правило. В обычном тексте, разумеется, запятая и не нужна.

Comment: behemothus, все скрины теперь в ответе. В грамматических справочниках сказано, что вопросительные местоименные слова – это признак вопросительного предложения. Заголовки такого типа представляют собой сложносочиненное предложение, части которого соединены союзом «и». Значит, местоименные слова «сколько» и «кто» здесь именно вопросительные, а не относительные. Потому что в разряд относительных они переходят только в качестве союзов и союзных слов в составе сложноподчиненных предложений. Заголовки можно считать вопросительными, несмотря на тенденцию опускать вопросительный знак в конце.

Answer (score 0):

---

Сколько денег ему нужно и кто может ему помочь — (такова) тема разговора.

Или: Количество денег и возможные помощники - тема разговора.

Это пример двух разных конструкций (сложное и простое предложение) со сходным содержанием. В нашем же случае мы имеем **нечто среднее (своеобразный гибрид)**, где, к примеру, два первых предложения **выступают в роли** однородных членов, а сказуемым является "тема".

Но в любом случае (при любом разборе)  **одиночный союз И связывает  предложения, отнесенные к общему сочетанию "тема разговора"**, поэтому запятая не ставится.

**Вопрос 2 (заголовок)**

2.Сколько денег ему нужно и кто может ему помочь

Думаю, что и здесь запятая не нужна, произношение  без паузы. Предложения образуют единую конструкцию,  остается только объяснить почему.

Дело, как мне представляется,  в том, что  заголовки подобного рода - это сокращенная запись первого варианта, и хотя выражение "тема разговора" здесь отсутствует, оно по-прежнему подразумевается и связывает два эти предложения.

Comment: "Сколько денег ему нужно"  - вы считаете, что это придаточное?

Comment: Сколько денег ему нужно и кто может ему помочь — такова тема разговора. Это сложное предложение с сочинительной и бессоюзной связью. А вот с заголовком  сложнее. Это назывная конструкция, вопроса нет, поэтому используются, скорее,  относительные местоимения.  Похоже на  "придаточные" при отсутствующем главном предложении, и знаки препинания ставятся ставятся, как в СПП. Но это все предположения, материал надо проверять по авторитетным источникам.

Comment: Т.е. вы считаете, что это назывные предложения?

Comment: Да нет, Серж,  не назывные, конечно,  давайте скажем, что заголовок имеет номинативную функцию. Мы хотим не спросить кого-то, а просто назвать тему.